# Is the phrase "stop X from being an oddity" grammatical/idiomatic?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

Example:

> Mary was always called a freak for wearing old-fashioned clothes. One
>   day she decided to buy new ones, **so she would stop being called an
>   oddity.**

Is this correct grammar/usage? If not, what's the correct option?

Comment: I can tell you that it is grammatical and idiomatic, but if you can tell us which part of that last phrase you are wondering about, we can try to explain it more thoroughly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**so she would stop being called** is an awkward  way of expressing the idea "{she did something} so people would stop calling her odd".

You could say "{she did something} to stop people from calling her odd".

> I want to stop being called a freak.<sup>freakish</sup>
>
> I want people to stop calling me a freak.<sup>normal</sup>

I wouldn't call it anything worse than "awkward" or "freakish", however.  I would like it to stop being used. But people do speak that way. I will meet them halfway:

> I want being called a freak to stop.